# Python: Get name of function which called this function

Tags: python

Currently I can get the function name using this command:

```
sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

I want to put it in of function like this:

```
def func_name:
    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

this function always returns 'func_name'. Is it possible to get the name the function which is calling this function?

Comment: `traceback` gives you the whole stack - https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html so I presume you can get what you want from there

Comment: It's worth noting that while you _can_ do this (see afeldspar's answer), 99% of the time when you think you want it (except for purposes like debugging a mess of threading code, or learning about how Python works by exploration), you really don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding the use of `sys._getframe`:

```
import inspect

def bar():
    current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
    previous_frame = current_frame.f_back
    print previous_frame.f_code.co_name

def foo():
    bar()

foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code you posted is working for you, then try giving `_getframe()` an argument of 1.  The argument tells *which* frame to return, and it defaults to 0; you want 1, meaning the frame that frame 0 was called from.

However, the "inspect" module may be what you want, if you need it to work across more implementations of Python.

Comment: Also, if you already have the current frame and want its parent, you can always use `f_back` to walk up the stack.